# FileNotFoundException on spark.scheduler.allocation.file

Tags: java, apache-spark

I'm trying to implement fair scheduling in spark via pools. As said in [docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/job-scheduling.html), I just need to put fairscheduler.xml file in classpath and spark will automatically create described pools, but it didn't work for me. I tried to put allocation file property in different ways:

`("spark.scheduler.allocation.file", "conf/fairscheduler.xml")`

`("spark.scheduler.allocation.file", "/conf/fairscheduler.xml")`

`("spark.scheduler.allocation.file", "src/main/resources/conf/fairscheduler.xml")`

`("spark.scheduler.allocation.file", "/src/main/resources/conf/fairscheduler.xml")`

But it only works if I specify the absolute path, like `C:/project_name/src/main/resources/conf/fairscheduler.xml`. Of course that is not acceptable. Do someone know how to put correct path to allocation file here?

Comment: Is this a Maven build?

Comment: Yes, this is maven build with standalone spark

Answer (score 0):

I would use the key `/fairscheduler.xml` in that case, and put it directly in the build `resources` folder to keep things as simple as possible

Answer (score 0):

I'm faced same issue and resolved this config

```
config("spark.scheduler.allocation.file","file:///opt/spark/conf/fairscheduler.xml.template")

// scheduler file at local

conf.set("spark.scheduler.allocation.file", "file:///path/to/file")

// scheduler file at hdfs

conf.set("spark.scheduler.allocation.file", "hdfs:///path/to/file")
```

See [the documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/job-scheduling.html#fair-scheduler-pools).